# Efficently find files in specific directories

Tags: java, nio

I have a simple problem: I iterate a large and deeply nested directory structure using `Files.walkFileTree` like this:

```
final int CUTOFF = 5;
final List<Path> foundList = new ArrayList<>();
Files.walkFileTree( codeRoot, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
             throws IOException {
        String rPath = codeRoot.relativize( dir ).toString();
        int level = rPath.length() - rPath.replace("/", "").length();
        if (dir.getFileName().toString().equals( "target" ) || level < CUTOFF) {
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
        return FileVisitResult.SKIP_SUBTREE;
    }
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile( Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs ) 
            throws IOException {
        if (file.getFileName().toString().endsWith( ".txt" )) {
            foundList.add( file );
        }
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
} );
```

My goal is to add all files under a specific directory `target` that I know is at most `CUTOFF` levels under `codeRoot`.

I'm looking for a more efficient way to do this in terms of necessary `stat()` calls or someone saying "can't be done".

Language level is Java8.

Comment: Why do you think it could be done? walkFileTree uses NIO which means it is infrequently as good as native walk in terms of performance. If you invoke this frequently, you can use some caches. An example of the cache: the last modified time of the directory (in some filesystems) to cache directories which haven't changed since the last call.

Comment: @MladenAdamovic I was mainly thinking I might be missing some algorithmic short-cut, since my implementation is as naive as it gets. Also, I have no clue if `relativize()` has an impact on fs performance I could avoid. Your idea about repeated run optimization is a good one, thanks!

Comment: What are you using as your measure of speed? Have you implemented a similar solution in C/C++ as a reference point? Why do you think it's inefficient so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm presented is a one-time query. In this case, you're stuck with a linear-time search through all the directories. You can't minimize away the need to examine each directory that way. You can look at caching, of course, but if you're going to bother with cache coherency and need high performance you might also consider building an index. In either case I'll address the question you asked, which is about a one-time query.

The version of `Files.walkFileTree` you're using walks the entire tree, including all the files and directories past the maximum level. You're explicitly excluding them by parsing the path name, a technique you rightly think might not be efficient. The solution is to always read the documentation. There's a second version of `Files.walkFileTree` with maximum depth as an explicit argument. From a [tutorial on walking the file tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html):

> The second walkFileTree method enables you to additionally specify a limit on the number of levels visited and a set of FileVisitOption enums.

If you use the second method you'll only visit candidate files within the maximum level, and you can avoid all the code that prunes subtrees.

Comment: Good catch about the extra method. That prompted me to look at the `walkFileTree` implementation, which uses a `stack` to keep track of directories to visit. A return of `SKIP_SUBTREE` will pop the stack element, which *should* end traversal further than this (by not generating new stack entries for this directory), correct? So you're saying the two are equivalent but using the `maxDepth` variant, I can cut the manual depth calculation?

Comment: @mabi The operation that `SKIP_SUBTREE` does is usually called "pruning". It stops traversal at the current node, avoids traversal at all of its children, and simply continues _as if_ the subtree were traversed. So, yes, your analysis of this behavior is correct. For the second question, the implementation that uses `maxDepth` is indeed keeping track of depth (in fact, it does so already, since it's the size of the stack), alleviating you of the need to calculate it. Tip: never write code that someone else has already written for you.

Comment: Fair point. Since you've hit both the "you can't do more" and the "there's room for optimization" points, I'll award you the bounty EOD unless somebody blows my mind before that.

Answer (score 1):

Optimization options:

1) register for notification when directory changes: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html
this can work in the background

2) (less optimal) use caching of not changed directories (in some filesystems): use the last modified time of the directory to cache directories which haven't changed since the last call

Using grepcode, I could not find how relativize is implemented, I think it might be implemented natively. I guess it is implemented with simple string operations of already pulled values and I don't think it is accessing `stat()` at all. You can test it although, make a dummy code (which doesn't work anything useful) with and without `relativize` and measure real impact when traversing a lot of files. Than you can be sure you are not losing much performance due to `relativize`

Comment: `relativize()` is JVM+OS dependent, in my case it's implemented via `sun.nio.fs.UnixPath`. The decompiled code is kinda hard to track through.

Comment: create an testing code (which traverses directory with doing nothing useful) with and without relativize and test performances. If you get +30% less performance  which has relativize, you should try to figure out how to fix that